# Azure AD B2C - Change application in Sign-Up/Sign-In policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing Sign-Up/Sign-In policy and I want to change the Application that is associated with. When I select the new Application that I want in the drop down the change does not get saved (ie. it reverts back to what it was previously. I don't see a save button either. I've tried editing the policy and hitting the save button in that window as well as pressing the Run now button but no luck. Am I overlooking something?

[image]

Comment: What’s your real goal ?

Comment: @spottedmahn I wanted to configure it for multiple environments (local/dev). My plan was to create an B2C application and policy for each environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The B2C Policy run screen does not save your last known run profile. This page is to test your policy, and as such will reset all application, domain, reply URL etc settings each time.

Answer (score 1):

Policies can be run against **all** applications.

The run now screenshot you have demonstrates this.